# can not figure out how to keep my double...a double

Tags: integer-division

```
if ((double) (points / tries) > hiScore) {
                        hiScore = (double) points / tries;
                        hiPoints = points;
                        hiTries = tries;
```

I cannot understand why hiScore, or even points / tries, always remain = 0 (points and tries are both ints, same as hiPoints and hiTries)

Comment: I forgot to mention that hiScore is a double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if ( ((double) points / tries) > hiScore) {
                    hiScore = (double) points / tries;
                    hiPoints = points;
                    hiTries = tries;
```

Or even this (shouldn't be necessary, because of the priority cast operation has over division):

```
if ( (((double) points) / tries) > hiScore) {
                    hiScore = ((double) points) / tries;
                    hiPoints = points;
                    hiTries = tries;
```

You need to cast your integer variable before division operation.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.